# Multiple assignments to the same variable

Tags: php, function, variables

Why do I get a parse error with this code:

`$func = "do_{$something}" = $func();`

?

It should be correct because

```
$func = "do_{$something}";
$func = $func();
```

works...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Because the assignment works [from right to left](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Look at this code as an example:

```
$a = $b = 3;
```

If assignment would work from the left, this'll be parsed as:

```
$a = $b;
$b = 3;
```

which would give you an undefined variable error.

Instead, it's parsed as:

```
$b = 3;
$a = $b;
```

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to do is equivalent to the following:

```
"do_{$something}" = $func();
$func = "do_{$something}";
```

Which obviously has syntax errors.  Your second block of code doesn't read well, as you're overwriting the function name variable with the result of the function call.  A cleaner way to do this would be:

```
$result = call_user_func('do_' . $something);
```

Comment: It does *something* – it sets `$func` to `do_{$something}`, then executes the function whose name is `do_{$something}`, then sets `$func` to its return value. So it does something pretty stupid, but it does *something*...

Comment: @lonesomeday:  I suppose that was confusing.  I've updated my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

It is invalid because the `=` operator is [right-associative](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). This means that the right-most `=` is executed first, so your code is actually equivalent to this:

```
"do_{$something}" = $func();
$func = "do_{$something}";
```